# JavaScript Beginner : do while loop for repeat

Tags: javascript

I have no idea why the do while code cannot repeat ask the question...and after I put the do while ...there is no function at all...

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
var done;
do{
var num = prompt("Enter Number", "0") //prompt user to enter the number
number = parseInt(num); //parse the num to number
var i;

document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0">');
for(i=1;i<=12;i++) 
    {
    document.write("<tr><td>" + i  + " x " + number + " = " + number*i + "</td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}while(window.confirm("Do you want to enter another number to show another multiplication table?")



</script>
```

Comment: he means that after he put in the while, the script stopped working completely.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a paranthesis end on the }while... line

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var done;
do{
  var num = prompt("Enter Number", "0") //prompt user to enter the number
  number = parseInt(num); //parse the num to number
  var i;

  document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0">');
  for(i=1;i<=12;i++) 
  {
    document.write("<tr><td>" + i  + " x " + number + " = " + number*i + "</td></tr>");
  }
  document.write("</table>");
}while(window.confirm("Do you want to enter another number to show another multiplication table?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the ')' symbol to close the `while`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v499jL7j/)

```
while(
    window.confirm(
        "Do you want to enter another number to show another multiplication table?"
     )
) // <- This one
```